# How to post List<int> in params in Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Example : https://example.com/things?category=100&category=101&category=105

```java
  @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("service_name") 
  void functionName(
    @Query("category") List<Int> categories
  ) {};
```

this will send it like `https://example.com/things?category=100&category=101&category=105`

Answer (score 2):

Its done like this, all u have to do is implement ... 3 dots after the String and you will allowed to enter multiple queries

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("service_name") 
void functionName(@Query("category") String... categories) {};
```

and u call it like this

```
 YourClass.functionName("100","101","105")
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
 @Headers("Accept:application/json", "Content-type:application/json")
 @POST("service_name")
 fun functionName(
        @Query(" category[]") categories: List<String>
    ): Single<CategoriestResponse?>
```